# How to fetch specific JSON data in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looking to fetch the details 'Contacts' from the below JSON.

```
{
"id": "65664546",
"name": "Employee 1",
"contacts": [
    {
        "id": "56546564",
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Carter",
        "email": "carter101@google.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "565465644",
        "firstName": "Simon",
        "lastName": "Deol",
        "email": "simon505@google.com"
    }
]
```

}

Below is the **interface** I have defined:

```
export interface employee {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  contacts: contact[];
}

export interface contact {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
}
```

Please can you advise, what would the Httpget method and subscribe method for it look like.

Comment: Multiple employees so multiple contact arrays.. how would you like it? Or do you want to know how to display it?

Comment: Hi MikeOne, I would like to access Contacts for single selected employee. Thank you

Comment: @PratikSurani Please check my answer and let me know does it work for you or not. And also let me for farther help. Best wishes :-)

Comment: I am looking for the get and subscribe method to fetch this data and display in component template

Comment: @PratikSurani I have updated my answer please check now. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to use ***pluck*** rxjs operator to get specific key data from object and below is the code to get and subscribe data from API.**

Here is the [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-subscribe?file=src%2Fapp%2Finterface.ts)

appcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { pluck } from "rxjs/operators";
import { GetServiceService } from "./get-service.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  constructor(private getAPI: GetServiceService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAPI
      .getData()
      .pipe(pluck("contacts"))
      .subscribe(r => {
        console.log(r);
      });
  }
}
```

getService.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { employee } from "./interface";


  export interface employee {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  contacts: contact[];
}

export interface contact {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
}
@Injectable()
export class GetServiceService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  getData(): Observable<employee> {
    // this.httpClient.get('url for api will be used')
    return of({
      id: "65664546",
      name: "Employee 1",
      contacts: [
        {
          id: "56546564",
          firstName: "James",
          lastName: "Carter",
          email: "carter101@google.com"
        },
        {
          id: "565465644",
          firstName: "Simon",
          lastName: "Deol",
          email: "simon505@google.com"
        }
      ]
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Suraj, Many thanks for your help. It worked indeed!

Comment: Thanks Can you please mark my answer correct.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to do that. Its done now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a problem with `Contact: Contacts[];` in `employee` interface. It should be `Contacts: Contact[];`. To convert `string` to `JSON` you can use code like =>

```
myEmpArray:employees;

ngOnInit(){
   this.myEmpArray = JSON.parse(this.temp); //Here temp is your JSON Text.
   let mycontact=this.myEmpArray.employees[0].Contacts[0];
   console.log(mycontact);
   console.log(this.myEmpArray);
  }
```

**You can use `http.get` and `subscribe` Method like below** =>

```
  myEmpArray:employees;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').subscribe((data) => {
      this.myEmpArray = data;
    });
  }
```

`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';` import this line in your component file and import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`

**Note:** You can check how to use http `GET`in Angular in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-http-get?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts). After getting the data you can parse JSON to object as given above.

Comment: Hi Linker, Thank you for your post. I am looking for Get method and Subscribe method. Please can you advise on that.